# Where to find a proof of the Julia-Fatou theorem for the connectedness of Julia sets?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-dynamics

There's a theorem that if all the orbits of the critical points of a complex polynomial map are bounded, the corresponding Julia set is connected. Also, if all the critical orbits escape to infinity, the Julia set is a cantor set. Where can I find a proof of this theorem? I have tried to find it but I cannot.

Comment: Wanna outline a proof lol...im kinda cheap...or at least why a statement like this "ought to be true" (e.g. the Jordan curve theorem ought to be true for certain easily understandable reasons, and these reasons don't contain the formalism used in the proof of the theorem)

Comment: The textbook mentioned by @lhf was widely available as a preliminary set of notes that you can find [on the arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9201272). The theorem you seek appears as theorem 17.3 in those notes. The basic idea is that the map $\varphi$ that conjugates a polynomial $f$ of degree $n$ to $z^n$ near $\infty$ can be iteratively extended analytically via the identity $\varphi(f(z))=\varphi(z)^n$ until you meet a critical point. This yields a sequence of simple closed curves that collapse down on the Julia set. This is very similar to the proof that the Mandelbrot set is connected.

Answer (score 1):

Milnor's book, [Dynamics in one complex variable](https://press.princeton.edu/titles/8117.html), contains this theorem on page 96:

[image]